# Ms Access filter reports in runtime mode

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

Does anyone knows how to filter reports the right way within Access runtime mode? 
The usual code with `DoCmd` doesn't work.

This is what I tried for the report:

```
Private Sub Befehl217_Click()
DoCmd.OpenReport "Tagesbericht", acViewPreview
End Sub

Private Sub Bezeichnungsfeld26_Click()
DoCmd.GoToControl "DateFilter"
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdFilterMenu
End Sub
```

This didn't work. Access complained that *"FilterMenu isn't available"*.

I tried to create a context menu but this only displayed me cut, copy and paste.

Comment: What have you tried? None of us can help you unless I have something to work with, in particular a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A great way to explain this is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Also, do check out the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931) and [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: It says that FilterMenu isnt available

Comment: That's actually the field within the report where i wanted the Filter to appear. I got this working in my form but no mather what i do it won't work in reports

Comment: When i click on to the field it jumps into the DateFilter. The Date get's selected and the Filter Appears

Comment: yes it should be ... as i said it works exactly this way in my form but not in the report

Comment: Your report includes a control named `Bezeichnungsfeld26` and when the user clicks in that control, you want to bring up the filter menu for that control.  Is that correct?

Comment: yes that's what it should do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You confirmed your report includes a control named `Bezeichnungsfeld26` and when the user clicks in that control, you want to bring up the filter menu for that control.

When the user clicks in that control, it has the focus, so there is no need for `GoToControl`.  And you don't want to go to a different control if you want the user to filter on `Bezeichnungsfeld26`.

Disable the `GoToControl` line ...

```vb
Private Sub Bezeichnungsfeld26_Click()
'DoCmd.GoToControl "DateFilter"
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdFilterMenu
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *Filter* property:

```
Me.Filter = "[YourField] = " & somevalue & ""
Me.FilterOn = True
```

or, to expand on your current method:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "Tagesbericht", acViewPreview, , "[YourField] = " & somevalue & ""
```

If you filter for a date you must pass a properly formatted string expression for the date:

```
Dim FilterDate As Date

FilterDate = Date

DoCmd.OpenReport "Tagesbericht", acViewPreview, , "[DateFilter] = #" & Format(FilterDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
```

Comment: Do i write this in code for example in the onclick for a field? 
Or is this in the propertys of the field?

Comment: ok well this didnt worked either ... do you know how to work with shortcut menus? maybe i can try this i would create a new question because i tried already something but still having issues with that

Comment: The code will work, so your implementation is probably fuzzy. Shortcut menus don't work in the runtime environment, if I recall correctly.

Comment: i tried to check for a specific data for example because thats the only thing i need to filter for example with today, tomorrow, yesterday and also select dates like the form filter provides .... 

so i added this to my reports onopen `DoCmd.OpenReport "Tagesbericht", acViewPreview, , "[DateFilter] = " & 01.06.2016& ""` 

this wasnt working? and istn this opening the report in preview mode with the filter? i wouldn't need it that way because i'm having a navigationform with tabs that include my form and 3 reports

Comment: i got it working with a shortcutmenu it works even in runtime